# KnockoutJS mapping plugin with complex objects

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

Based on the KnockoutJS mapping [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) what I am trying to do seems really straightforward, however I am not getting the results I expect.

So for some simple test html-

```
<div data-bind="with: rootItem">
<p data-bind="text: subProperty"></p>
    <div data-bind="with: subObject">
        <p data-bind="text: subSubProperty"></p>
</div>
```

and this simple view model and application

```
var vm = function(){
this.rootItem = ko.observable();

this.loadData = function(data){

    //map the rootObject here
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data,{},this.rootItem());

    //this.rootItem is undefined
    console.log(this.rootItem());
 };


};
   //create new viewmodel
    var myVM = new vm();
   //create some dummy data with nested objects and properties
    var data = {
    subProperty: "Top Level Property",
    subObject: {
        subSubProperty:"Sub Level Property",
        },
    };
  //load the data
  myVM.loadData(data);
  //apply the vm
  ko.applyBindings(myVM);
```

So the vm.rootObject never gets set. Am I missing something about the ko.mapping plugin behavior?

This implementation of the loadData function gets the desired result, but adds the extra step.

```
this.loadData = function(data){

    //map the rootObject here
     this.rootItem(ko.mapping.fromJS(data));

    //this.rootItem is an object with a nested object and observable properties
    console.log(this.rootItem());
 };
```

Why does the first method fail? In the documentation it states pretty clearly that "The third parameter to ko.mapping.fromJS indicates the target."

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mA77A/4/) demonstrating what is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation is right "The third parameter to ko.mapping.fromJS indicates the target.".
But you provide the wrong target:

because when you call `ko.mapping.fromJS(data,{}, this.rootItem());` the `this.rootItem` is initialized with `undefined` so the mapping plugin cannot use it a target.

Use an empty object when creating the `rootItem` and it will work fine:

```
var vm = function(){
    this.rootItem = ko.observable({});

    this.loadData = function(data){     
        ko.mapping.fromJS(data,{}, this.rootItem());             
     };
};
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nemesv/a3sdy/).

Comment: Thanks that makes sense now. Was is interesting is that when you use the with:binding to get the behavior you want, the observable has to be undefined. If you pre-load an empty object, the with binding tries to resolve the children, and the binding fails. However, if you start with an undefined object and use someObject(ko.mapping.fromJS(data)) this method, the behavior works as expected with the with binding